# Converting arrays of strings from matlab to java

Tags: java, arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, data-conversion

I have a java GUI which I have written, it has some underlying back end to it that is currently in MATLAB.

I am trying to call all the back end functions from the Java portion for ease of use, and I have successfully been able to run the MATLAB functions from java using the MATLAB controller (https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/), however the implementation seems to be limited to numeric data, whereas the data I am dealing with is an array of Strings (Call it a 90 x 8 array of strings just to be safe).

I was able to successfully see an array of numbers in Java using the MatlabController library.

I have also tried using the [MATLAB Compiler SDK](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-compiler-sdk/), however there were multiple internally generated errors when I tried running the code.

I am out of ideas of how I might accomplish the conversion.  Would JSON be an unreasonable option to pursue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it the wrong way. Don't send a matlab array to java. Instead construct the java array in matlab, and send that to java. Like how it is done here http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javaarray.html.